# Not getting customer orders in Magento 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento-1.8, email, sales-order

I currently have magento sending Emails to the customer upon making an order, but i am not getting bcc'd or a separate email notifying me at all.

I do have all of the emails I wish to receive the email listed in `Config > System > Sales Emails >`

I have also read about magento forcing you to use a cron job to send the emails, but that seems to be only relevant in magento 1.9 and beyond.

All other resources I have googled in regards to this issue have discussed modifying code that is not even existent in my magento installation.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the email address (domain part) in the BCC field same as your magento hosting url?

If you do I would suggest to test with some other email (diff domain) to see if email gets through .. if it gets then no native magento issue but hostings part I guess ,, I had recently client with similar issue,,

hth, k

Comment: I have a few different emails, some with different domains, user@example.com, user@gmail.com, etc

Comment: Glad that worked out for you @gary, if my answer helped you please mark it as solution

Answer (score 2):

i changed the email in "New Order Confirmation Email Sender" from "Sales Representative" to "General Contact" and now it works without a hitch